# mysql query doesnt work by php | work by phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

One of my PHP functions just not work. Mysql returns success but it doesnt UPDATE column that i want. I really no have idea why that problem exist.

So here is the function that UPDATING it:

> function savePhone($phone) {
>
> ```
> dbConnect();
> $q = "UPDATE site SET phone = '$phone' WHERE id = 0";
> $r = mysql_query($q) or die (mysql_error());
> if ($r) return $q;
> else return "error";
> ```
>
> }

Here is var_dump-ed example query that works fine when using phpMyAdmin.

> 'UPDATE site SET phone = '111111' WHERE id = 0'

Im using Apache

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You may also be **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Your `else return error` is pointless. If the query fails, the `or die()` will kill the script right there.

Comment: do you really have a record with id = 0?

Comment: What error do you get? Are you connected to the database?

Comment: Add a `echo mysql_error();` after the mysql_query call and you'll see what's going on. Possibly did not select database?

Comment: I AM CONNECTED TO DATABASE and i get NO ERRORS. Function saying that record has been updated, when checking that column in db its has not changed. But when I paste that var_dump-ed statment in phpmyadmin its actually updating record - working well // using root (master) user in phpmyadmin and as php user

Comment: DATABASE is also selected in dbConnect function. Sorry but i can't use any pdo (too much changes)

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($r)` ?

Comment: No error. Mysql says nothing bad happened. There are two possible explanations. 1) You are viewing the wrong database. 2) You do not have record with id = 0.

Comment: There is another solution i just find out. I have forgotten to put unique key for id comumn in db. Thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong actually **die()** stops the script from executing

```
$r = mysql_query($q) or die (mysql_error());
```

if **die()** is called this part is never gonna be executed and no value is returned to **$q**

```
if ($r) return $q; 
  else return "error"; 
}
```

use instead

```
$r = mysql_query($q);

if(empty(mysql_error())) return $q;
   else return "error";
```

Comment: well, it doesnt change nothing. thats cuz DIE is never called - query is ok - success but doesnt change variable in column.

Comment: mysql_error return empty if there is no error check the updated answer

Comment: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: Anyway it just started to work when i used all { } within if / else